# delete google slides with appscript from google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

I am updating my content in a google slides deck from a google sheet with a code that I found, and it is all working fine. However when I run the script I want the current slides after the nth slide to be deleted before it adds new slides. It is even possible?

[Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mJ-Cjy768K7q4IQdSvVei1vNcUzJh_UwMsPRfaw9vro)
[Google Slides deck](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1tUGlI9l6t61MfrrCHKZ0-F3xRPwPqu1hXybqxPJzjs0/)

```
function createOneSlidePerRow() {

  // Replace <INSERT_SLIDE_DECK_ID> wih the ID of your 
  // Google Slides presentation.
  let masterDeckID = "INSERT_SLIDE_DECK_ID";

  // Open the presentation and get the slides in it.
  let deck = SlidesApp.openById(masterDeckID);
  let slides = deck.getSlides();

  // The 2nd slide is the template that will be duplicated
  // once per row in the spreadsheet.
  let masterSlide = slides[2];

  // Load data from the spreadsheet.
  let dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2').getDataRange();
  let sheetContents = dataRange.getValues();

  // Save the header in a variable called header
  let header = sheetContents.shift();

  // Create an array to save the data to be written back to the sheet.
  // We'll use this array to save links to the slides that are created.
  let updatedContents = [];

  // Reverse the order of rows because new slides will
  // be inserted at the top. Without this, the order of slides
  // will be the inverse of the ordering of rows in the sheet. 
  sheetContents.reverse();

  // For every row, create a new slide by duplicating the master slide
  // and replace the template variables with data from that row.
  sheetContents.forEach(function (row) {

    // Insert a new slide by duplicating the master slide.
    let slide = masterSlide.duplicate();

    // Populate data in the slide that was created
    slide.replaceAllText("{{test1}}", row[0]);
    slide.replaceAllText("{{test2}}", row[1]);
    slide.replaceAllText("{{test3}}", row[2]);

    // Create the URL for the slide using the deck's ID and the ID
    // of the slide.
    let slideUrl = `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/${deck.getId()}/edit#slide=id.${slide.getObjectId()}`;

    // Add this URL to the 4th column of the row and add this row
    // to the data to be written back to the sheet.
    row[3] = slideUrl;
    updatedContents.push(row);
  });

  // Add the header back (remember it was removed using 
  // sheetContents.shift())
  updatedContents.push(header);

  // Reverse the array to preserve the original ordering of 
  // rows in the sheet.
  updatedContents.reverse();

  // Write the updated data back to the Google Sheets spreadsheet.
  dataRange.setValues(updatedContents);

  // Remove the master slide if you no longer need it.
  //masterSlide.remove();

}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `when I run the script I want the current slides after the nth slide to be deleted before it adds new slides.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. When I run the scipt it adds new slides and keeps the old slides so what I want to do is to 1. delete all slides after slide x (e.g. slide5) 2.run the script above. Alternativly if I can for example say, delete slide 5,7,8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution:

Use [Slide.remove()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#remove).

#### Code snippet:

```
const nIndex = "nth index from which slides get removed";
const deck = SlidesApp.openById(SLIDE_ID);
const slides = deck.getSlides();
slides.slice(nIndex).forEach(s => s.remove());
```